# Européen as européin

Tags: prononciation

An excellent student challenged me on « européen » today. I had corrected his final /ɛ̃/ to /ɑ̃/ based on the spelling, but he wanted me to double-check.

Sure enough, WordReference [claims](https://www.wordreference.com/fren/europ%C3%A9en) it's /ɛ̃/! The Canadian recording also clearly aligns, though the French recording sounds a little more mid-mouth, perhaps halfway between the two (or maybe that's just the speaker's realization of /ɛ̃/). Other dictionaries agree: [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/europ%C3%A9en), [Larousse](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/europ%C3%A9en/31729), etc. But Forvo recordings [present some variation](https://forvo.com/word/europ%C3%A9en/#fr), at least to my ears.

What's up? Is there one acceptable pronunciation or two? If it's /ɛ̃/, is that a modern change or has it always been thus?

Comment: Now that you have the excellent answer of Jiliagre: remember those lyrics by the singer Arno (not a native French speaker, though): *putain, putain/c'est vachement bien/ nous sommes quand même tous des Européens*: no doubt that that *européen* rhymes with *putain*...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To answer your questions, there is now only one acceptable pronunciation of *européen* in /ɛ̃/ but there used to be a pronunciation in /ɑ̃/ alongside the other one.

In the "langue savante", some words ending in *-en* or *-ien* were pronounced either /ɛ̃/ or /ɑ̃/ until the 18th century when /ɛ̃/ replaced /ɑ̃/ altogether.  The words concerned were names of peoples or figures from the classical world that had *anus* in Latin.  *Européen*, it seems, retained a dual pronunciation probably longer than the others.

We can quote Thurot in *De la prononciation française depuis le commencement du XVIe siècle d'après les témoignages des grammairiens*, published in 1883:

- Nous avons vu ci-dessus (p.436) que les mots en *ien* dissyllabe, qui appartiennent en général à la langue savante, ne se prononçaient *ian* qu'à Paris.  En ce qui touche les noms communs et les adjectifs, l'usage ne paraît avoir hésité que sur *chrétienté* et *quotidien*, mais il a longtemps été partagé entre *ien* et *ian* dans la prononciation des noms propres.  La prononciation vulgaire *ien* [/jɛ̃/] tendait à l'emporter dans la seconde moitié du XVIIe siècle sur la prononciation savante *ian* [/ɑ̃/] ; D'Ablancourt (1654) dit dans la première des *Remarques sur la traduction de Lucien* : « Je dis *Lucien* et non pas *Lucian*, pour suivre la prononciation commune, puisque dans les langues aussi bien que dans la jurisprudence *communis error facit jus*. »

Thurot further cites Vaugelas (1585-1650):

- Depuis peu d'années seulement nous faisons terminer en *en* [/ɛ̃/] la plupart des noms propres et plusieurs autres tirés du latin, où il y a un *a* et qui en latin finissent en *anus*, comme l'on disait autrefois *Tertullian*, *Quintilian*, *Saint-Cyprian*… mais aujourd'hui l'on prononce *Tertullien*, etc… Du temps de M. Coeffeteau [early 17th century], on disait *les* *Pretorians*, et il l'a toujours écrit ainsi, au lieu de dire *pretoriens*.

When it comes to *européen*, Hindret in *L'art de prononcer parfaitement la langue françoise* (1696) deals with exceptions to *en* pronounced as /ɑ̃/:

- Exceptés aussi les dernières syllabes de ces mots, *cananéens*, *caldéens*, *galiléen* dont l'*e* de la syllabe *en* retient sa prononciation naturelle en latin, il ne faut donc pas prononcer *caldéan* mais *caldéen*.  Le mot *européen* se prononce pourtant *européan*.

Voltaire, as late as 1755, has an interesting note in the dedicatory epistle to his play *L'orphelin de la Chine*.  He writes in the dedication:

- Comment les Chinois, qui au quatorzième siècle, et si lontemps auparavant, savaient faire de meilleurs poëmes dramatiques que tous les Européans, sont-ils restés toujours dans l'enfance grossière de l'art…

Here's his note:

- Le Père Du Halde, tous les auteurs des lettres édifiantes, tous les voyageurs, ont toujours écrit *Européans*, et ce n'est que depuis quelques années qu'on s'est avisé d'imprimer *Européens*.

The issue was obviously contentious and the Académie felt it necessary to specify in its *Dictionnaire* (1762):

- Européen, éenne. adj. Qui appartient à l'Europe. On ne dit point EUROPÉAN. C'est par cette seule raison que ce mot se met dans le Dictionnaire.

To finish, in view of one your remarks, I should also point out that there's a rather significant number of words with *en* or *em* in the middle of them that have /ɛ̃/ and not /ɑ̃/ as might be expected.  Off the top of my head, *appendice*, *Benjamin*, *pentagone* and other compounds with the Greek root *penta* (but *Pentecôte* is /pɑ̃tkot/), *benzène*, *benjoin* (made famous by Baudelaire in the poem *Correspondances*), *sempiternel* (though /sɑ̃pitɛʀnɛl/ is probably heard more often), pensum, Gassendi, the philosopher, and probably other words as well.

Comment: A well-researched answer. For its thoroughness I'm going to accept it even after the fact. And I get to have my eyes opened a second time, this time in regards to "Benjamin"! Good grief... Ça va aller jusqu'à quel point avec cet /ɛ̃/ ?? :)

Comment: On the prononciation of en in the middle of words with a Latin origin : http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=4444

Answer (score 7):

I'm afraid you have to revert your correction.

The very large majority of the words ending in *-en* are pronounced /ɛ̃/ and the rest are pronounced /ɛn/ (e.g. amen, cérumen, golden, hymen, lichen, pollen). An obvious and possibly unique exception is the preposition or pronoun *en* always pronounced /ɑ̃/.

Comment: If so, this resolves a long-standing "knot" that had yet to come untied in my mind... according to the *-en* = /ɑ̃/ rule I had internalized, *bien* was an annoying exception! One day in a linguistics course, I remember my professor who happened to speak French (non-natively) corrected my /bjɛ̃/ to /bjɑ̃/. Perhaps that's why I've been inflicting this same mis-correction ever since. I'll leave this open a little longer before accepting only because of how surprised I am at missing such a basic thing, but thanks in advance.

Comment: I guess a reason for the mistake is that when *en* is followed by a *t* like in *argent*, the /ɑ̃/ ending is no more an exception but very common.

Comment: Same for the other letters that can follow it (sens, tend). Not to mention it being pronounced /ɑ̃/ at the start and middle of words (entier, tendre, Cendrillon...) The end-of-word thing seems to me an odd phenomenon given the generally consistent behaviour of digraphs in French.

Comment: I agree with the pronunciation [ɛn] for the words that are directly borrowed to Latin (amen), Greek (hymen) or Britton (bigouden). For the English word "golden" (I guess you mean the apple ?), though,I would rather pronounce [ən] more or less like in English, but I guess this will be subject to personal or regional variations (I cannot think of another anglicism ending in -en where we can compare, except all the plural forms of lean words with "-man" (eg rugbymen) which are obviously pronounced [ɛn] on the model of the English pronunciation).

Comment: @Greg There is also *open* pronounced either more an English way as /opən/ or a French one as /opɛn/.

Comment: I also thought of *token*, used in the IT industry - also pronounced /tokən/ or /tokɛn/.