# Pronunciation of IEN

Tags: prononciation

The letters IEN are usually pronounced /jɛ̃/ (e.g. [chien](https://www.wordreference.com/fren/chien), musicien, gardien, bientôt, ancien, rien), but sometimes they are pronounced /jɑ̃/ (e.g. [science](https://www.wordreference.com/fren/science)). Is it possible to predict the pronunciation of this group of letters or must it be learned case by case?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A similar question with relevant answers: [Européen as européin](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/41944/europ%c3%a9en-as-europ%c3%a9in)

#### Ways to guess based on the position in a word

The pattern seems to be, approximately, that word final *-ien* and *-iens* are pronounced /jɛ̃/.

Word-medial *-ien-,* when followed by a consonant letter other than N, is pronounced /jɑ̃/ in a number of words: *orient, omniscient, science, récipiendaire.* However, the very common verb forms *vient, tient, viendra(s etc.), tiendra(s etc)* are pronounced with /jɛ̃/ in exception to that.

Also, some words that are spelled with *-ien-* followed by another consonant letter are derived from words where *-ien* is word-final, and have the same /jɛ̃/ pronunciation as the shorter word. This would explain *bientôt* and *chrétienté.*

#### The different pronunciations usually developed from different historical sources

The actual reason for the difference seems to be historical development, rather than the position of the letters. It looks like there are three main sources of IEN in French words:

1. Diphthongization of what was originally a single short e sound /ɛ/ in Latin. This results in /jɛ̃/, not /jɑ̃/ (as in Latin *b**e**ne*, *r**e**m*  > French *bien*, *rien*).

   This diphthongization only affected *e* when it occurred in a stressed open syllable (a syllable ending in a vowel) in Latin. When short *e* came before a consonant cluster in Latin, such as *-nt-* or *-nd-,* it didn't diphthongize to *-ie-,* so Latin *ventus, tendit* became French *vent, tend.*

   The verb forms *vient* and *tient* have *-ie-* despite the following *-nt* because they come from Latin *venit* and *tenet*: the *-nt* in the French forms is not from a Latin consonant cluster, but was created later on by the loss of the vowel that was originally before the final *-t.* I don't know how the forms *viendra* and *tiendra* developed.

   From the etymological perspective, the pronunciation of the word *[fiente](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/fiente)* as /fjɑ̃t/ is unexpected.
2. The change of an originally separate /i/ vowel to a glide /j/ before another vowel. When that following vowel is *e* before a Latin consonant cluster starting in N, the result is /jɑ̃/, as in French *science, orient* < Latin *scientia, orientem*.

   This kind of sequence in Latin can also correspond to a French pronunciation with two syllables, /i.ɑ̃/ or /ijɑ̃/, depending on the preceding sounds or the accent of the speaker. For example, in French *client* from Latin *cl**ie**ntem,* the preceding cluster /kl/ might make it more likely to be pronounced with /ijɑ̃/ as /klijɑ̃/.

   These kind of words all seem to have been borrowed from Latin with fairly little change in spelling.
3. The change of stressed *a* in an open syllable to *ɛ̃* when nasalized. In most contexts, *ɛ̃* from this source was spelled AIN (as in French *vain* from Latin *vanus*). But when preceded by a front vowel or a palatalized consonant, it apparently developed to the diphthong /jɛ̃/.

   Examples:

   - Latin *c**a**nem* > French *ch**ie**n* : the a in the stressed open syllable became *ɛ,* nasalized by the following n to *ɛ̃*. The *c* at the start of the word was palatalized to *ch,* which was a regular sound change, and a glide /j/ developed between the palatalized consonant *ch* and the vowel *ɛ̃*
   - Latin *-ianus* to French *-ien* in *gard**ien**, music**ien*** etc.

     I think that the *-ien* in *musicien* and so on is always pronounced in a single syllable, the same as with /jɛ̃/ from diphthongized short e. I'm not totally sure though.

Comment: I've heard lien (< ligámen) pronounced with two syllables despite being a product of Bartsch's law, but that's probably due to the influence of lier (where a morpheme boundary splits the ie sequence, which blocks glide formation for some speakers)

Answer (score 2):

In complement to **[user sumelic's](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/42845/17649)** answer and pertaining to medial "ien" followed by a consonant I will mention the words  in which "ien" is followed by "ne", the resulting combination being "ienne"; "ien" is not pronounced, instead  "ienne" is and this pronunciation is regularly **/jɛn/** (there might be a very few exceptions where it is **/ijɛn/**.

In such a group are the words that result by derivation in a feminine form and which regularly show the change "/jɛ̃/ →  /jɛn/" in pronunciation. It's an enormous subclass.

```
- Adrien → Adrienne /ijɛn/          jacobien → jacobienne
- Autrichien → Autrichienne         lagrangien → lagrangienne
- académicien → académicienne       chrétien → chrétienne
- chien → chienne                   ancien → ancienne
- mien → mienne                     arien → arienne
- tien → tienne                     terrien → terrienne
- sien sienne                       …
```

In addition must be mentioned all those words which exist, along with a derivation  by adding "ien(…)" to a stem, a dérivation in "ienne(…)";  all those formations result in the change "/jɛ̃/ →  /jɛn/" in pronunciation. It's a small subclass.

```
- tiens,tient → tienne(s), tiennent     maintiens, maintient → maintienne(s), maintiennent  
- viens, vient → vienne(s), viennent       soutiens, soutient → soutienne(s), soutiennent
```

No dérivation (only a few words)

```
-  obsidienne, persienne, Vienne, Étienne,
```